# Ubuntu 18, Screen won't turn off after x min

Tags: laptop, screen

How are you?
I have Ubuntu 18 , I remember i changed somethign to gdm or gdx somethign like that to help battery saving fo rmy laptop. After that My screen wont turn off after x min, no matter what i change it to, even 1 min ro 10 mins Screen stays always on. 
Any fix for that?
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Ubuntu 18 is both wrong and inaccurate.  Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, with a release back in April of 2018 (so 18.04) & another this month (18.10 or 2018.October).  If you used a command to make the change, you could type `history` (which will provide a history of the commands you have entered), which may jog your memory so you can provide more clues as to your change.  Both Ubuntu 18.04 & 18.10 use `gdm3` as default display manager so maybe you changed your 'dm` from `gdm3` to something else... Can you see anything in your command history?

Comment: You could try installing GNOME Tweaks via `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` if you haven't yet installed it. Open the menu and select "Reset to Defaults." A few pieces of information that would be helpful to know as well; what graphics card are you using, and what drivers? I read that there were some bugs in 18.04 with the Nvidia drivers. Also, what exact version of Ubuntu "18" are you using? 18.04 or 18.10?

Comment: 265  nvidia-settings
  266  prime-select query
  267  prime-select intel
  268  sudo prime-select intel
  269  prime-select query
  270  sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
  271  sudo apt install bbswitch-dkms
  272  sudo killall apt apt-get
  273  sudo apt install bbswitch-dkms
  274  sudo apt-get update
  275  tlp
  276  sudo apt-get upgrade
  277  tlp
  278  sudo gedit /etc/default/tlp
  279  sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
  280  tlp
  281  tlp stat
  282  sudo tlp stat
  283  sudo apt install bbswitch-dkms
  284  prime-select query
  285  top

Comment: @Eamonn  I have nvidia 1060, i installed the drivers for it nvidia392 i think. In general my laptop ive been told is to new for the ubuntu. Even my touchpad doesnt work out of the box.  My laptop is Acer predator helios 300 8th gen

Comment: I wouldn't say "too new," it's just that Nvidia has a plethora of trouble with Linux. AMD and Intel work quite well. My Intel and AMD laptops have all worked out of the box, even my brand new Dell laptop. I would suggest you wait for a driver update and hope for the best. You've also ran some GDM related commands, which you mentioned in your OP. However I'm not convinced that's what's caused this issue.

Comment: @guiverc  Hi thanks again soooo what should i do????